# DownloadStrinAsync error during parsing in Windows Phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

i've an issue... I would create an app that scraping the result of a google search.. but when I try to use downloadstringasync the debug return me an error "Impossible to assign 'void' to a local variable ..."

You say how I can resolve it?

This is the code

```
        public class SearchResult
    {
        public string url;
        public string title;
        public string content;
        public FindingEngine engine;

        public enum FindingEngine { google, bing, google_and_bing };

        public SearchResult(string url, string title, string content, FindingEngine engine)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
            this.engine = engine;
        }
    }

public static List<SearchResult> GoogleSearch(string search_expression, 
  Dictionary<string, object> stats_dict)
{
  var url_template = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&safe=active&q={0}&start={1}";
  Uri search_url;
  var results_list = new List<SearchResult>();
  int[] offsets = { 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48 };
  foreach (var offset in offsets)
  {

    var searchUrl = new Uri(string.Format(url_template, search_expression, offset));
    var page = new WebClient().DownloadStringAsync(searchUrl);
    var o = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(page);

    var results_query =
      from result in o["responseData"]["results"].Children()
      select new SearchResult(
          url: result.Value<string>("url").ToString(),
          title: result.Value<string>("title").ToString(),
          content: result.Value<string>("content").ToString(),
          engine: SearchResult.FindingEngine.google
          );

    foreach (var result in results_query)
      results_list.Add(result);
  }

  return results_list;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DownloadStringAsync` doesn't return anything i.e. a `void` so you cannot simply assign a variable to it.

You need to add an event handler to `DownloadStringCompleted` which will be fired when `DownloadStringAsync` completes.

```cs
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
client.DownloadStringAsync(searchUrl);

static void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
  // e.Result will contain the returned JSON. Move the code that parse the result to here.
}
```